# sql trigger using two tables data

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

So I have three tables. First two have ID column and "rank" column (an integer). I will be inserting into the third table both IDs (ID1, ID2) but I need the trigger to check whether they are the same rank before I can insert. I can't get it to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT ON TABLE_C 

BEGIN
IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT TABLE_A.id, TABLE_B.id
FROM TABLE_A JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.rank = TABLE_B.rank
WHERE TABLE_A.id = inserted.id1 AND TABLE_B.id = inserted.id2 )
THEN
PRINT 'Not the same rank'
ROLLBACK
END
END;
```

I'm using Oracle db.

Comment: The syntax is so wrong ... have you looked at any Oracle trigger documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use 'Rollback' or 'commit' in Oracle Triggers -
[please refer this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:486421585357)

I think you can modify your trigger as follow -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trigger1
    AFTER INSERT ON Table_c
    FOR EACH ROW
  DECLARE
    l_Count NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO l_Count
      FROM Table_a
      JOIN Table_b ON Table_a.Rank = Table_b.Rank
     WHERE Table_a.Id = :NEW.Id1
       AND Table_b.Id = :NEW.Id2;
    IF l_Count = 0 THEN
      DELETE FROM Table_c
       WHERE Id1 = :NEW.Id1
         AND Id2 = :NEW.Id2;
      --PRINT 'Not the same rank'
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('Not the same rank');
    END IF;
  END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are two kinds, `BEFORE` and `AFTER` Triggers. If you want to check whether the data has the same rank before the data is inserted, then you should use a **BEFORE** Trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLE_C
```

Then the logic will follow.

**UPDATE:** You can easily [raise application error](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/errors.htm#sthref2006). Such as:

```
IF HasSameRank == 0 THEN
    raise_application_error(-21013, 'Not the same rank');
END IF;
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I did try both but there's still something wrong.

Comment: @semihyagcioglu please suggest how to fail insert in trigger with "before insert" condition..

Comment: It says "Error(5,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE_B" when expecting one of the following:     ) , with group having intersect minus start union where    connect "
It says the error is where the JOIN is, on TABLE_B